# insert ignore .....select is locking the table inside select

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb, percona

I am using Percona MySQL 5.5.28 MySQl server on linux system with ext4 file system and 23 GB ram out of which 15 GB approx is allocated to MySQL....
I fired a query something like below

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO table_A SELECT field1,field2,....fieldn FROM table_B;
```

The above query is locking  table_B....
Due to which alter query which i have fired later on the table_B locked.

**Above two table are of Innodb and My entire db operations is only Innodb storage engine only.....**

Can Anyone please tell me why MySQL locked table_B has locked here ?

If Possible Please let me know when and which queries will lock a table in MySQL ?

Comment: Read [Does INSERT IGNORE lock the table even if it ignores the insert?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18170235/does-insert-ignore-lock-the-table-even-if-it-ignores-the-insert)

Comment: i have read the article before but my question is why table_B locked...There are only 3 threads connected one is mine(root) other executing alter and another executing INSERT IGNORE...SELECT...Please help me out

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but in case someone stumbles on it like I did, the short answer is that adding SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED; before the query sometimes works.

More info:
[How to improve INSERT INTO ... SELECT locking behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640898/how-to-improve-insert-into-select-locking-behavior)

Note that the mentioned innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog approach was deprecated as of MySQL 5.6.3. (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog).