# Myisam locking issue

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

`| 3282164856 | user       | someIp:43814 | dbname | Query       |        0 | update                                                                | insert ignore into TABLE(COL1,COL2,DATE,COL3) values ('10523365','1343046',now(),'Y')`

TABLE is MYISAM but this query is causing TABLE to be locked.

My questions about this:

1. Since its a insert ignore query. Why its showing update on processlist?
2. Why insert ignore is causing lock as i know only update can lock a table (unless there are holes)?

Answer (score 0):

You are incorrect - MyISAM locks tables on insert:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/table-locking.html

---

for more information on what `INSERT IGNORE` means and how it works, see this question: [Does INSERT IGNORE lock the table even if it ignores the insert?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18170235/does-insert-ignore-lock-the-table-even-if-it-ignores-the-insert)

Comment: also why its showing update instead of insert on processlist